# Eclipse Errors - FRC - Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, plugins, error-handling, g++

I am having some issues. I am trying to run some FRC plugins in Eclipse. This program executed is a test program. My goal is to be able to deploy but it does not seem to work.

[image]
[image]

What are these errors and why am I getting them?

Thanks, Base2101

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to create an arcade drive command, I would suggest starting with the template that is included in the plugins.  Go to create a new project but instead of doing it the normal way, click other and then click either C++ or Java WPI Development folder.  Then click Robot Java Project or Robot C++ Project. After that, the folders and classes will be done for you.

To create an arcade drive class, you will need to right click on the commands folder and create a new class, and again go into new>other>WPILib Robot C++/Java Deveopment>Command.

To see a full tutorial, see this page [here](https://wpilib.screenstepslive.com/s/4485/m/13809).